# Segue from Master to Detail UITableView, where the second one has a grouped style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, segue, uitableview

I really do feel like I'm starting to lose my mind I've been working at this so long with no progress. All I want to do is simply click on a row in a UITableView and segue to another UITableView that has the grouped style format. In other words, I want to do what the image below is showing.

I can get the concept to work beautifully if the second screen is a **View Controller** with labels I've added to it. My code to segue from the master to detail view works, but the problem is this way does NOT look like the image below.

The second screen in the image below shows a grouped-style table. Yet every time I delete the **View Controller**, add a **TableViewController**,  add labels to the table, set the style to grouped, and create an outlet for a property of the label in the detail view contoller class, I get this **"Cannot have a prototype object as its destination"** error.

I read somewhere that the issue has something to do with the table needing its own class configured with **UITableViewCell** as its subclass. But when I try adding a class and making the connection to that interface file (control + drag), the connection cannot be made.

What I'd really like is for someone to tell me what I am doing wrong so I can finally implement what is pictured below. Is there a tutorial for this? I've looked and cannot find one.

Someone please give me some suggestions or link me to a tutorial if you can find one.

Additional info: using XCode 4.6. I've looked through Apple's documentation and it did not help. I'm creating the project with storyboard.

[image: Screen Shot 2013-02-14 at 9.50.58 PM]

Comment: How are you adding the labels to the table?

Comment: I drag and drop the labels from the Object Library to the table view.

Comment: What I'm doing is instead of adding a View Controller for the second scene in the above picture, I 1) add a Table View Controller to the storyboard, 2) add a custom View Controller class to the project, 3) associate my second table view controller with my second custom table view controller class (in identity inspector), 4) switch Content to 'Static Cells' (in Attribute inspector), 5) add a custom table view cell class to the project, 6) associate the cell in the second table view with the second custom table view cell class,

Comment: 7) drag and drop a label from the Object library into the cell. But when I try to make the connection to the second custom table view cell class via control + drag, it cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to connect an outlet to a dynamic prototype cell, and you can't do that. You can solve it one of two ways. You can make that table view have static cells, and connect outlets from the table view's .h file. Or, if you need dynamic cells, you need to create a subclass of UITableViewCell, and add any outlets or properties to it. In IB, change the class of your cell to your subclass, then you can connect outlets from the cell to its subviews.

The fact that the second table has a grouped table view style has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: For the second table, do I have to create a second UITableViewController custom class, and a second UITableViewCell custom class. If so how do I handle the segue like this? For a simpler, table-to-detail view way, the second is just a UIViewController with labels, so no need to set up a table. So do I need to set up the second table for the scenario I pictured above? And if so how do I segue the data? Pass the array from one table to the second?

Comment: @Frank, The easiest way is to use static table view cells. You will need a subclass of UITableViewController for that, and outlets to all your labels. The segue is just a normal control drag from the first table controller to the second.

Comment: I tried it that way, but ended up with a logic error when transitioning from first to second table. Bellow are some of the steps. 
1) Add a Table View Controller onto the storyboard (beside the first table view controller). 
2) Add a custom UITableViewController class to the project and associate the new view controller with the new class (in identity inspector). 
3) In Attribute inspector, change Content to Static Cells.  
4) Drag label(s) onto cell. 
5) Create outlets to all label(s) (in table view controller .h file from step 2)
6) This goes on for 10 more steps with code involved.

Comment: Is there any way you can point me to a tutorial that will tell me how to make an app as pictured above? Or May I send you my code and you can check it? Or even better, you can send me a same app that does what is pictured above?

Comment: @Frank, I don't have a good sample app available. You can send me your app if you want to rdelmar@comcast.net

Comment: Thank you. I just sent a sample app.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. Let me explain it in simple.

**Problem:**
You have add a UILabel in UITableViewCell and you are trying to add it's IBOutlet in UIViewController.

**So how to solve?**

It depend on your need.

1. If you need only one label than dont add in UITable or in UITableViewCell.
   Don't take UITableViewController take UIViewController add UITableView and UILabel in it.
   (Add UILabel in UIViewController not in UITableView).
2. If you want to add this UILabel in every UITableViewCell than you have to go for custom UITableViewCell.
   Create a subclass of UITableViewCell and create an IBOutlet of UILabel there.

You will get many tutorial on internet for custom UITableViewCell.

All the best....

Comment: I've done the second option you've given, but then I can't see the label(s) on the screen when I run in the simulator. Do I create a second UITableView controller class, and set up the second table there? And if so do I reference the second UITableViewCell class for this second table? Also, how do I get the data from the first table to the second this way via the segue? I need to do that to populate the detail data.

Comment: There are NO tutorials to be found on this subject, amazingly. If you can find one by some miracle, PLEASE give me the link!

Comment: For the second table, do I have to create a second UITableViewController custom class, and a second UITableViewCell custom class. If so how do I handle the segue like this? For a simpler, table-to-detail view way, the second is just a UIViewController with labels, so no need to set up a table. So do I need to set up the second table for the scenario I pictured above? And if so how do I segue the data? Pass the array from one table to the second?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/